mysql Deadlock: update by secondery index
-- create table
CREATE TABLE info (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  useridx INT UNIQUE,
  name VARCHAR(100)
 );
-- prepare data
INSERT INTO info (id, useridx, name) VALUES (1, 100, 'Alice');
INSERT INTO info (id, useridx, name) VALUES (2, 200, 'Bob');

-- concurrency update sql
UPDATE `INTO` SET `name`='xxx' WHERE useridx = 100        -- sql1
UPDATE `INTO` SET `name`='xxxxx' WHERE id = 1             -- sql2

-- useridx = 100 and id = 1 is the same line data

Is my deadlock analysis correct?

sql1 holds two locks: one on the index useridx and one on the primary key id.
sql2 holds one lock: the primary key id.

enter image description here




session  A     exec sql1
session  B     exec sql2
session  C     exec sql1




t1
sql1: lock  useridx




t2

sql2: lock  id



t3
sql1: lock id     (blocked)




t4


sql1: lock useridx     (1213,'Deadlock found when trying toget lock; try      restarting transaction)



session A wait session B's id lock,
session C wait session A's useridx lock,
so Deadlock ? it that current?
if session B will release it's id lock soon?

func TestUpdateDeadlock(t *testing.T) {
    type V struct {
        Id      uint64 `gorm:"primary_key;column:id;type:int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT;not null;comment:'ID'" json:"id,omitempty"`
        Useridx uint64 `gorm:"column:useridx;type:bigint(20);not null;comment:'用户ID'" json:"useridx,omitempty"`
    }
    dsn := "root:root@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/dbname?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed to connect database: %v", err)
    }

    var v V
    result := db.Raw("SELECT id, useridx FROM INFO ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1").Scan(&v)
    if result.Error != nil {
        t.Fatal(result.Error.Error())
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        wg.Add(2)

        // UPDATE `INFO` SET `name` = 1729823365 WHERE id = 1;
        go func(t *testing.T, i int64) {
            defer wg.Done()
            if err := db.Table("INFO").
                Where("id = ?", v.Id).
                UpdateColumn("name", fmt.Sprintf("%d", time.Now().Unix()+i+1)).
                Error; err != nil {
                t.Logf("update by id: %s", err.Error())
                t.FailNow()
            }
        }(t, int64(i))
        // UPDATE `INFO` SET `name` = 1729823365 WHERE useridx = 100;
        go func(t *testing.T, i int64) {
            defer wg.Done()
            if err := db.Table("INFO").
                Where("useridx = ?", v.Useridx).
                UpdateColumn("name", fmt.Sprintf("%d", time.Now().Unix()+i+1)).
                Error; err != nil {
                t.Logf("update by useridx: %s", err.Error())
                t.FailNow()
            }
        }(t, int64(i))

        // fix: this will not deadlock
        // UPDATE `INFO` SET `name` = "1729823365" WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM `INFO` WHERE useridx = 100);
        //go func(t *testing.T, i int64) {
        //  defer wg.Done()
        //  if err := db.Table("INFO").
        //      Table("INFO").
        //      Where("id = (?)",
        //          db.Table("INFO").
        //              Where("useridx = ?", v.Useridx).
        //              Select("id").
        //              Limit(1)).
        //      UpdateColumn("name", fmt.Sprintf("%d", time.Now().Unix()+i+2)).
        //      Error; err != nil {
        //      t.Logf("update by useridx: %s", err.Error())
        //      t.FailNow()
        //  }
        //}(t, int64(i))

    }
    wg.Wait()
}

What is the exact true cause of this deadlock?

It seems like the Go code doesn't match the table schema described in the question. This makes it hard to read. Could you please clean this up a bit?

Sorry, I updated it synchronously.

Use innodb status monitor to get exact reason for the deadlock. What you described in the question should not lead to a deadlock as exclusive locks set by data modification statements are serialized by default. This means you can't have more than one exclusive lock on the same row.

Okay, I'll check the deadlock log.
